# Fancybox on CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fancybox

Is there [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) available anywhere on the [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so - the large CDNs only host very popular libs and fancybox just ins't that widely used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is Yandex CDN (http://www.yandex.com/--big russian search engine)

Available Versions: 1.3.4, 1.3.1
Path: http://yandex.st/jquery/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Answer (score 26):

Yup, looks like it [got added](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/commit/fa2ebd70987b101804d9ac78ff04c3c08b2a9100) to [cdnjs.com](http://www.cdnjs.com/) on Jan. 3 2012!

[The website](http://www.cdnjs.com/#/search/fancybox) hasn't been updated with the info but here's the link to the [Fancybox 2.0](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.pack.js) library:
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.pack.js

Comment: That's cool, but you can't use it without the CSS! Still have to download it and host yourself..

Comment: I usually will just add the css into my existing style.scss so it gets compiled, compress, and served inside one style.css file instead of multiple network requests…

Comment: Please note that Fancybox 2.0 is no longer licensed under the MIT-license. You cannot use it in commercial projects without a license.

Comment: The CSS is on there too: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.css

Comment: You can see a listing (by version) of the fancybox assets on cloudflare (css [full and min], js, images) at: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/fancybox/

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't, but you can submit it yourself for inclusion in http://www.cdnjs.com/#/search/

Answer (score 3):

The latest version (as of today), 2.1.0 is hosted on jsDelivr, **with** the CSS
http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!fancybox

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so if so I believe the would have mentioned it [here](http://fancybox.net/howto)